# How to reference a websphere Resource Environment Provider in ejb-jar.xml?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, ejb-3.0, websphere-8

With reference to this question and this URL(both given below) , I have exactly same requirement but in ejb-jar.xml , I know I have to insert this part

```
      <resource-env-ref>

       <resource-env-ref-name>MyConstants</resource-env-ref-name>

      <resource-env-ref-type>com.ibm.acme.ree.lib.Config</resource-env-ref-type>

      </resource-env-ref>
```

but this section cannot directly be inserted inside the tag of "ejb-jar" , it has to be inside sub tags like "enterprise bean" or "assembly descriptor" or "relationships" etc, please help me in getting the exact xml code for this.

[How to reference a websphere Resource Environment Provider in web.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25839671/how-to-reference-a-websphere-resource-environment-provider-in-web-xml)

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0611_totapally/0611_totapally.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this can be used as a starting point:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0"
>
  <enterprise-beans>
    <session>
      <ejb-name>TestBean</ejb-name>
      <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
      <resource-env-ref>
        <resource-env-ref-name>MyConstants</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>com.ibm.acme.ree.lib.Config</resource-env-ref-type>
      </resource-env-ref>
    </session>
  </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

I've omitted other required elements such as `<ejb-class>` and `<session-type>`, which will be required unless you're using annotations.  Well, if you're using annotations, using `@Resource` is much easier than `<resource-env-ref>` anyway:

```
@Stateless
public class TestBean {
    @Resource
    private Config config;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I am doing it using @Resource now and the application runs fine without any error, and given it correct path to refrenciable in shared libraries

I have given Check1234 JNDI name to the remote class, now while I call it using ctx.lookup in client I get error "Config cannot be resolved" :(

Comment: do I need to create a Stub class for resource in my package ?